# CUDA Visual Studio error "The command (a really long command) exited with code 255"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I'm trying to learn cuda and convert a current project of mine into using it and I am getting this error:

> Error  MSB3721 The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code="sm_52,compute_52" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdx64\Debug\vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\cudaMain.cu.obj "C:\Users[my usr name]\source\repos\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2_Solution\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2\cudaMain.cu"" exited with code 255.

I am using a .cuh file how do I declare classes it gives me a warning saying "attribute does not apply to entity." Do I need to label I also get a warning telling me "Warning  C26812  The enum type 'cudaError' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3)."

.cuh file

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

using namespace std;

static unsigned const int maxCircuitSizeG = 200;
static const int inputSizeG = 16;
static const int outputSizeG = 9;
static const short childParentAmountG = 10;

__host__ __device__ class Gate {
public:
    char type;
    int children[childParentAmountG];
    int parents[childParentAmountG];
    bool output;
    __host__ __device__ Gate();
};
__host__ __device__ class Circuit {
public:
    Gate gates[maxCircuitSizeG];
    bool inputs[inputSizeG];
    bool outputs[outputSizeG];
    double score;
    unsigned int averageCounter; // up to 4,294,967,295
    int size;
    __host__ __device__ Circuit();
};

__host__ __device__ unsigned int randumb(void);
unsigned int randumb2(void);

__host__ __device__ bool IsBoolInParents(Gate gate, Gate circuit[], bool boolToFind);
__host__ __device__ bool XORgateOutput(Gate gate, Gate circuit[]);
__host__ __device__ bool IsIntInArr(int arr[], int arrSize, int num);
bool IsShortInArr(short arr[], short arrSize, short num);
bool IsIntInVector(vector<int> vec, int num);
__host__ __device__ bool PushInt(int arr[], int arrSize, int num);
bool PushShort(short arr[], short arrSize, short num);
__host__ __device__ int CountCircuitSize(Gate circuit[]);
int CountCircuitSize2(Gate circuit[]);
__host__ __device__ void RemoveIntAndShiftArr(int arr[], int arrSize, int indexToRemove);
void RemoveShortAndShiftArr(short arr[], short arrSize, short indexToRemove);
int IntPow(int num, int exponent);
int BinaryToDecimal(bool bits[], int byteSize, bool firstIsMostSignificant);
string IntToString(int num);
void DecimalToBinary(int n, bool byte[], int byteSize);
void ShiftBinary(bool byte[], int byteSize, bool shiftLeft, int shiftAmount);
string BinaryToString(bool byte[], int byteSize);
__host__ __device__ void CopyGate(Gate& to, Gate from);

__host__ __device__ void RandomGateType(Gate circuit[], int circuitIndex);
__host__ __device__ void DestroyGate(Gate circuit[], int indexToRemove, int circuitSize);
__host__ __device__ void CleanCircuit(Gate circuit[], int circuitSize);
__host__ __device__ void AddChild(Gate circuit[], int circuitSize, int index);
__host__ __device__ void AddParent(Gate circuit[], int circuitSize, int index);
__host__ __device__ void CreateGate(Circuit& circuit, int indexToAdd, int circuitSize);
__host__ __device__ void CreateGate2(Circuit& circuit, int indexToAdd, int circuitSize);
__host__ __device__ void SafeFixCircuit(Gate circuit[], int circuitSize);
__host__ __device__ bool GateOutput(Gate gate, Gate circuit[]);
__host__ __device__ void Process(Circuit& circuit);
__host__ __device__ void ProcessFromCharArr(Circuit& circuit, char arr[]);
__host__ __device__ void RandomCircuit(Circuit& circuit, int circuitSize, int startingChildParentAmount);
__host__ __device__ void RemoveChild(Gate circuit[], int circuitSize, int index);
__host__ __device__ void Mutate(Circuit& circuit, int growChance, int shrinkChance, int grow, int shrink, int rate, int intensity);

void CreateAdderCircuit(Gate circuit[]);

string CircuitToString(Circuit circuit);
void SaveCircuit(string path, Circuit circuit, int circuitSize);
void FileToCircuit(string path, Gate circuit[]);

__host__ __device__ void InitRndPop(Circuit population[], int popSize, int startCircuitSize, int startChildParentAmount);
void InitPopFromFile(Circuit population[], int popSize, string path);

vector<string> MakeRndSample(int sampleSize, string path);

__host__ __device__ void Score3(Circuit& circuit, char arr[]);

__host__ __device__ void CopyCircuit(Circuit from, Circuit& to);
__host__ __device__ void CopyCircuitToPopulation(Circuit circuit, Circuit population[], unsigned short populationSize);
void CopyCircuit2(Circuit from, Circuit& to);
void CopyCircuitsToPop(vector<int> circuitsIndexes, Circuit population[], unsigned short populationSize);

__host__ __device__ void ScoreAverageFromArray(char arr[], int arrSize, Circuit& circuit);

__host__ __device__ void RandomBruteForceImproveFromArray(Circuit& circuit, char arr[], unsigned int arrSize, unsigned int maxSearch);

void fileToCharArr(char arr[], int size, string path);
```

the .cu with the definitions is too big to include but none of them have the **host** **device** thing they don't need that do they?

main .cu file

````
#include "LogicSimCuda.cuh"
#include <stdio.h>
cudaError_t improveCircuitPopWithCuda(Circuit* circuit, char arr[], int arrSize, unsigned int size);

__global__ void addKernel(Circuit *circuit, char arr[], int arrSize, const int maxSearch)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    RandomBruteForceImproveFromArray(circuit[i], arr, arrSize, maxSearch);
}

int main()
{
    const int populationSize = 1024;
    Circuit *population = new Circuit[populationSize];
    InitPopFromFile(population, populationSize, "C:/Users/voidm/Documents/LogicSimProjectGIT/LogicSim/Circuits/day2/Sun_Dec_20_12_54_59_2020.txt");
    unsigned const int fileSize = (inputSizeG + outputSizeG + 1) * 65536;
    char* trainingArr = new char[fileSize];
    fileToCharArr(trainingArr, fileSize,"C:/Users/voidm/Documents/LogicSimProjectGIT/LogicSim/src/Eight-Bit-Adder-Data.txt" );

    cudaError_t cudaStatus = improveCircuitPopWithCuda(population, trainingArr, fileSize, populationSize);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "improveCircuitPopWithCuda failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << population[0].score;


    return 0;

}

cudaError_t improveCircuitPopWithCuda(Circuit* circuitPop, char arr[], int arrSize, unsigned int size)
{
    Circuit *dev_circuit;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_circuit, size * sizeof(Circuit));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_circuit, circuitPop, size * sizeof(Circuit), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    addKernel <<<1, size >>> (dev_circuit, arr, arrSize, 1000000);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }

    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(circuitPop, dev_circuit, size * sizeof(Circuit), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_circuit);

    return cudaStatus;
}
    ```

here is the output

>1>------ Build started: Project: LogicGateMachineLearning_V2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Compiling CUDA source file cudaMain.cu...
1>Compiling CUDA source file LogicSimCuda.cu...
1>
1>C:\Users\voidm\source\repos\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2_Solution\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdx64\Debug\vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\LogicSimCuda.cu.obj "C:\Users\voidm\source\repos\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2_Solution\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2\LogicSimCuda.cu"
1>
1>C:\Users\voidm\source\repos\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2_Solution\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdx64\Debug\vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\cudaMain.cu.obj "C:\Users\voidm\source\repos\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2_Solution\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2\cudaMain.cu"
1>ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_Z32RandomBruteForceImproveFromArrayR7CircuitPcjj'
1>cudaMain.cu
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 11.2.targets(785,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdx64\Debug\vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\cudaMain.cu.obj "C:\Users\voidm\source\repos\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2_Solution\LogicGateMachineLearning_V2\cudaMain.cu"" exited with code 255.
1>Done building project "LogicGateMachineLearning_V2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>LogicSimCuda.cu
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
__host__ __device__ class Gate {
public:
    char type;
    int children[childParentAmountG];
    int parents[childParentAmountG];
    bool output;
    __host__ __device__ Gate();
};
```

is illegal. Execution space specifiers (so `__host__` and `__device__`) apply to function and variable declarations and definitions, not types. A correct class declaration would simply be

```
class Gate {
    public:
        char type;
        int children[childParentAmountG];
        int parents[childParentAmountG];
        bool output;
        __host__ __device__ Gate();
    };
```

There might well be other problems in your code, but without seeing the actual compilation error log and lacking enthusiasm to wade through all the code dumped in the question, that is the source of the one compilation error you did identify.

Comment: That got rid of one warning, what is the error log? It says this is the ouput 1>ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_Z32RandomBruteForceImproveFromArrayR7CircuitPcjj'" thank you

Comment: The error log or list is the actual list of errors emitted by nvcc compiling your code. All you have put in your question is Visual Studio telling you what nvcc command it ran and that it failed. The error in your comment is completely unrelated to anything in your question, that is a project configuration issue probably

Comment: To see the output of `nvcc` in some cases it is necessary to increase the visual studio **verbosity**.  You can google for instructions about that.  Regarding the unresolved extern function, this function: `RandomBruteForceImproveFromArray` is called from your `__global__` kernel in one file, but refers to a function defined in another `.cu` file/compilation unit.  In that case, you must use "CUDA separable compilation relocatable device code generation".  Again, google will find results for you.  Related to that, your `main.cu` file shows no evidence of including your `.cuh` file.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry it does include my .cuh file in my main it was just a formatting error on my part. I set the relocatable device to true and I no longer have that error but I do now have this error "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code 700 after launching addKernel!"

Comment: And this warning: 
Warning  Stack size for entry function '_Z9addKernelP7CircuitPcii' cannot be statically determined LogicGateMachineLearning_V2

Comment: You're now on  to completely different issues.  I'm sure it's tempting to think of this post as your own personal helpdesk, but that's not really how this Q+A site works.

Comment: With the greatest of respect, you posted a question about a specific syntax error. You received an answer to that specific question. That is the end of the interaction as far as [SO] is concerned. If you have a different question(s) then ask it in a new post. But please keep in mind that (a) [SO] is a finite resource and not your personal help service, (b) questions are expected to be useful to everybody, not just you, so think carefully what questions you choose to ask and how you ask them. Note also that there are 12k questions here already, and lots of useful answers if you search.